# Layout with center of view matches center of central item with minimum padding

Tags: android, image, layout

I am trying to create simple layout with an image and two labels (one above the image and one below it). I use the inflated view to paint it to a canvas. My interest is to create the view with a rectangle that has as center the center of the image. Using fill_parent or match_parent dimensions for layout is not desired since the final view will occupy all the available space, not the minimal space (resulting in a too big bitmap).

This is the code I have used so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ivBeaconType"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/bt_beacon"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_above="@id/ivBeaconType" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="12dp" android:text="AABBCCDDEEFF" android:id="@+id/tvId"
        android:textColor="#72C8E0"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_below="@id/ivBeaconType" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="-99 dB" android:id="@+id/tvRssi" android:textColor="#FF0000"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This has a problem. The relative layout does not grow to fit both texts (the label above does not show up and the one at bottom is painted too close to the image). I could render correctly the view by aligning image below first text and third text below image but that would not result in a perfect center around image center (or by using a linear layout).

What can do? Another valid solution would be getting the center of the image relative to the layout drawing area. Any ideas?

Comment: An image describing what you are trying to achieve would be great

Answer (score 0):

I got it. getLeft()/getRight()/getTop()/getBottom() methods of a view return the relative position within parent. The only captcha is that they only return valid values after the layout phase so this solved my question:

```
    if (beaconBitmap == null)
    {
        /* Calculamos las dimensiones si no está creado el bitmap */
        beaconView.invalidate();
        beaconView.refreshDrawableState();
        beaconView.measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        beaconView.layout(0, 0, beaconView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                beaconView.getMeasuredHeight());
        ImageView ivBeaconType = (ImageView) beaconView
                .findViewById(R.id.ivBeaconType);
        Rect beaconIconArea = new Rect(ivBeaconType.getLeft(),
                ivBeaconType.getTop(), ivBeaconType.getRight(),
                ivBeaconType.getBottom());
        beaconBitmapCenterX = beaconIconArea.centerX();
        beaconBitmapCenterY = beaconIconArea.centerY();
    }
```